# Group of guardians who watch for time variants and destroy planets if needed

Tags: story-identification

So I remember parts of the plot but can't remember character names. One of the guardians disappeared and it causes distrust between the other guardians. There was a part where people summon a god who is actually from a different time and is destroyed by one of the watchers. A main character is left with knowledge of the event.

I read it within the last year or two (I believe). The guardians were humans once but were chosen to take on mantles of guardians and watch for changes or errors in timelines across a bunch of planets or worlds. There was also a guardian who was betrayed and left a trail of clues that one of the guardians was following.

Comment: It sounds a bit like "Time Riders", but I don't think that's the one you're looking for...?

Answer (score 8):

Finally found it. It's the *[Cradle](https://www.goodreads.com/series/192821-cradle)* series by Will Wight.

Goodreads summary of the first book, *[Unsouled](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30558257-unsouled)*:

> Sacred artists follow a thousand Paths to power, using their souls to control the forces of the natural world.
>
> Lindon is Unsouled, forbidden to learn the sacred arts of his clan.
>
> When faced with a looming fate he cannot ignore, he must defy his family's rules...and forge his own Path.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let us know! Be sure to register your account so you can log back in, in the future. In 1.5 days-ish you should be able to accept this answer to mark it as correct too!